# Install windows on slave HD, then remove Master HD and boot from slave

Tags: hard-drive, boot, windows-8.1

My master HD has developed bad sectors and I should eventually move the windows to my currently slave HD.

Is it possible to:

- Install a 2nd windows 8.1 on Slave.
- Still use the old windows 8.1 (until the 2nd one is ready with the software I need)
- Swap hard drives (slave <-> master) and still be able to boot the new windows on the 2nd HD?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are your hard drives connected with IDE connection? Since you are using 8.1 that's very unlikely. If not  ,you must be using SATA and SATA hard drives do not have this master - slave relationship. You can just install Windows on both HDD's and swap between by changing boot order from BIOS.

So, all you answers would be: Yes.

Comment: Oh... I did not notice that we no more have a jumper on hard drives. Thank you very much.